# Re-rendering component when props updates with createStructuredSelector

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, reselect, react-lifecycle

I will try and make this as short and sweet as possible while being detailed and descriptive. When my application initializes or loads for the first time, it makes an `api` call to fetch some `blog` data. Here is what that looks like more or less:

[image: Redux State Store]

As you can see the `api` successfully returns the `blogPosts`. I then reference these `blogPosts` in another component using `createStructuredSelector` from the `reselect` library. Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { compose } from 'redux';

import VisionBlogItem from '../../components/VisionBlogItem';
import { getBlogItem, getFollowingBlogItems } from './selectors';

export class VisionBlogItemPage extends React.Component { // eslint-disable-line react/prefer-stateless-function
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
    };

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.blogItem && <VisionBlogItem blog={this.props.blogItem} blogItems={this.props.blogItems} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

VisionBlogItemPage.propTypes = {
  dispatch: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  location: PropTypes.shape({
    pathname: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }),
  blogItem: PropTypes.object,
  blogItems: PropTypes.array,
};

VisionBlogItemPage.defaultProps = {
  blogItem: {},
  blogItems: [],
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return createStructuredSelector({
    blogItem: getBlogItem(ownProps.location.pathname.match(/([^/]*)\/*$/)[1]),
    blogItems: getFollowingBlogItems(ownProps.location.pathname.match(/([^/]*)\/*$/)[1])
  });
};

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    dispatch,
  };
}

const withConnect = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps);

export default compose(
  withConnect,
)(VisionBlogItemPage);
```

What these selector methods are doing, `getBlogItem` and `getFollowingBlogItems`, are checking the props location pathname end slug and using it to iterate and array to find the needed blog in the `Redux State Store`. They then get set to the props named `blogItem` and `blogItems` to be passed to the `presentational component` to render. That presentational component looks something like this:

[image: wireframe]

At the bottom of this presentational component are some links that will change the slug name. So if I'm at `localhost:3000/blogPosts/blog-post-0` and I clicked on one of the three blog posts at the bottom, it would then change the url to `localhost:3000/blogPosts/blog-post-1` or `blog-post-2`, `blog-post-3`, etc. These blog posts at the bottom are links from `react-router-dom` and the code is written as such:

```
<Link to={props.blogItems[2].fields.slug} style={styles.seeMoreLink}>
  <img src={props.blogItems[2].fields.articleImage.fields.file.url} style={styles.seeMoreImg} alt="" key="2" />
</Link>
```

So the idea is that it changes the slug of the url and renders the appropriate blog post. However, this is not what is occurring. The url slug does change and I can even see in my `container component` that the props update and change as well. The location pathname changes from `blog-post-1` to `blog-post-2`. My question then lies why does my component not re-render? I am aware of the life-cycle method of `componentWillReceiveProps`, but I do not know how to use it in conjunction with something like `createStructuredSelector` from `reselect`. Anyone who could possibly give me a clear path as to how I am suppose to handle this it would be greatly appreciated!